# What is block hour in ACMI lease?

Tags: airline-operations, airlines

What is difference between Block hour and Flight Hour?

In ACMI Lease of aircraft, prices are calculated based on block hours. What is a block hour and how are they calculated?

Can any one show me an example for a flight like this...

- Delay at Runway (takeoff): 20 Minutes
- Flight Time: 1 Hour and 40 Minutes

Then what could be block hours? 2 Hours or 1 Hour and 40 Minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block time starts when the aircraft is pushed back from the gate, and ends when it arrives at the corresponding gate.

It is the total time the aircraft is in use, typically only calculated for revenue movements.

Imagine a flight:

- Pushback 1000
- Taxi 1030
- Takeoff 1035
- Touchdown at destination airport 1445
- Taxi to gate 1500

Total block time is 5 hours

Comment: Dear, can you please tell me what is Taxi time and pushback for an aircraft?

Comment: Pushback is when the airplane is literally pushed back from the gate, normally with a tug. It is moved to a designated area where the pilots turn on the engines and then start taxiing under their own power. Taxi time is quite literally, the time spent taxiing the aircraft - normally calculated from the time the aircraft exits the active runway and ends when the aircraft arrives at the gate and the parking brakes are set (for arrivals), and the time the aircraft moves under its own power (for departures) to reach the active runway. The time spent on the active runway is not counted as taxi time

Comment: Thanks, it is really informative, can you also tell me what is Route Navigation Facility Charges? and how it is calculated?

Comment: You should ask a new question, as the comments are not for discussions.

Comment: As I am new, I have to wait for 2 days to ask new question, no worries, but thanks again

Comment: RNFC is an umbrella term which covers all kinds of flight charges (for example, landing and take off fees, parking fees, overpass fees) and differ from place to place. They would depend on your equipment type and what route you are flying, and what kind of services you would need if you stop (for example, technical stop fees are different than deplaning).